# Problemas con el carrito de Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

Es mi primera experiencia con el php y prestashop y estoy intentado crear un carrito.
Este es mi código para instanciar e inicializar el carrito:

```
                $cart = new Cart();
                $cart->id_shop_group = $context->shop->id_shop_group;
                $cart->id_shop = '1';
                $cart->id_customer = $customer->id;
                $cart->id_carrier = $transportista; 
                $cart->id_address_delivery = $id_address_delivery;
                $cart->id_address_invoice = $id_address_billing;
                $cart->id_currency = $context->currency->id;
                $cart->id_lang = $context->language->id;
                try {
                      $cart->add();
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $hasError = true;
                }
```

Este es mi código para añadir artículos y actualizar el carrito:

```
$cart->updateQty($item['quantity'], $existingProduct->id, $existingProductAttrId);
```

Finalmente me crea un carrito vacío todas las veces.
He probado muchas maneras y no he dado con la correcta, no sé si es una cuestión de configuración de la tienda o del carrito, no tengo mucha idea.

Curiosamente en otro servidor con presta (v.1.7.5.1) sí que funciona el mismo código

Espero que me podáis ayudar.

Gracias

Comment: La verdad es que así es como se hace, usando el método `updateQty()` de Cart, si no te está funcionando comprueba la respuesta del mismo, si es `false` lanza una excepción o algo, para enterarte. Yo comprobaría si los parámetros que le pasas al método son válidos, puedes pintarlos en el mensaje de la excepción o algo.